# HTML Email Issues

Tags: html, email, html-email

Since I can't use `margin-bottom` in html email. What is another positioning thing I could use. I have already uses `margin-top`, `padding-bottom`, and `padding-top`.These all haven't been useful at any in getting what I want to happen.

So I have 2 images. I want to place a buy now button on the bottom right hand corner of an image in order to only be able click on the buy button. What should I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the button to be on top of the image? or just below?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this:

**Html**:

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="">
  <a href="#">Click here</a>
</div>
```

**Css**:

```
.box{
  position: relative;
}
.box a{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<body margintop="0" marginleft="0" marginright="0">
```

Answer (score 2):

A reliable way to create vertical padding/margin in HTML email is to use the following:

```
<div style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:15px; font-size:15px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

This will give you a vertical space of 15 pixels; adjust and duplicate as necessary.

---

I can't tell how this works in the context of the rest of your question, but I'll trust you will know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code that you currently have to help take the guess work out of what you need. Because the answer could be as simple as what Radavel mentioned or it might just need something like

```
align="right"
```

or

```
style="float:right"
```

But that depends on how your code is setup to  determine what might be the right answer for you.

Also researching into what code to use and not to use would be helpful as well since not all email providers have the same setup when it comes to viewing a email. What might look great in one might not look that grand in another.